# How to count the number of positive and Negative word per sentences in my list of sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, dictionary

I am writing a function wich is supposed to count the number of positive word and negative word in a sentence and creating two dictionnary for each sentence listing the word present in the  lexicon and then summed up each dictionnary to get for each sentence the len of postive words and negative word.

I wrote a function but I ma having problem printing the dictionary for each sentences, it always append the word of the other sentences and it is not what I want

here is the code :

```
def pwd_3(texte, liste1, liste2):
    
    ''' Calcul de la polarité d'une phrase
    On récupère le nombre de mots positifs et négatifs 
    et on divise par le nombre total de mots dans la phrase '''
    
    d_neg = dict()
    d_pos = dict()
    d_0 = dict()
    
    
    texte = spacy_process(texte)
    #print(texte)
    
    liste_phrase =[]
    label = []

    for elt in texte:
        elts = elt.split()
        print(' "Phrase à traiter "  :' , elt, '\n')
        for w in elts:
            if w in lexiconpos:
                #print(w, ': est dans le lexique positif', )
                d_pos[w] =+ 1
                
            elif w in lexiconneg:
                #print(w ,': est dans le lexique négatif', )
                d_neg[w] =+ 1
            else:
                #print(w, ': ne se trouve dans aucun des deux dictionnaires', )
                d_0[w] =+ 1
        print(d_pos)
        print(d_neg)
a= ["Le film est superbe mais cette édition DVD est nulle !","J'allais dire déplorable, mais je serais peut-être un peu trop extrême."]
lexiconpos =['aller','superbe']
lexiconneg = ['nul', 'déplorable', 'extrême']

             
pwd_3(a, lexiconpos, lexiconneg)
```

here is the result :

```
"Phrase à traiter "  : le film être superbe mais ce édition dvd être nul 

{'film': 1, 'superbe': 1, 'édition': 1}
{'nul': 1}
 "Phrase à traiter "  : je aller dire déplorable mais je être pouvoir être un peu trop extrême 

{'film': 1, 'superbe': 1, 'édition': 1, 'aller': 1}
{'nul': 1, 'déplorable': 1, 'pouvoir': 1}
```

Here is the expected answer:

```
"Phrase à traiter "  : le film être superbe mais ce édition dvd être nul 

list of positive words for this sentence: {'film': 1, 'superbe': 1, 'édition': 1}
list of negative words : {'nul': 1}

 "Phrase à traiter "  : je aller dire déplorable mais je être pouvoir être un peu trop extrême 

list of positive words for this sentence:  {'aller': 1}
list of negative words : {''déplorable': 1, 'pouvoir': 1}
```

Comment: `d_pos[w] =+ 1` et al. Is that supposed to be `d_pos[w] += 1`?

Comment: you need to reset the value for d_pos , d_neg and d_0 to {} after each sentence iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you just have to clear the `dict`s for each `for` loop:

```
for elt in texte:
    d_pos = dict()
    d_neg = dict()
    d_0 = dict()
    elts = elt.split()
    print(' "Phrase à traiter "  :' , elt, '\n')
    for w in elts:
        if w in lexiconpos:
            #print(w, ': est dans le lexique positif', )
            d_pos[w] += 1
            
        elif w in lexiconneg:
            #print(w ,': est dans le lexique négatif', )
            d_neg[w] += 1
        else:
            #print(w, ': ne se trouve dans aucun des deux dictionnaires', )
            d_0[w] += 1
    print(d_pos)
    print(d_neg)
```

Because the `dict` are redefined in each iteration, you won't need to define them out the `for` loop, so you can eliminate those lines. *(note your incrementation syntax is wrong. I fixed it in this code)*

Comment: thank you, I get this error : "Phrase à traiter "  : Le film est superbe mais cette édition DVD est nulle ! 

le : ne se trouve dans aucun des deux dictionnaires
---> 40 pwd_3(a, lexiconpos, lexiconneg)
<ipython-input-186-a878c77bb92a> in pwd_3(texte, liste1, liste2)
     29             else:
     30                 print(w, ': ne se trouve dans aucun des deux dictionnaires')
---> 31                 d_0[w] += 1
     32 
     33         print(d_pos)

KeyError: 'le'